# Default file manager does not open

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, debugging

What the title says when I try to start nautilus on terminal this is the output:

```
(nautilus:5593): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv-    >connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:5593): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached

(nautilus:5593): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:5593): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:5593): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

PS: Krusader works fine though

Comment: Same with me on 16.04!